# Suppress automatic confirmation of deletion in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to write a silent script that deletes files older than 14 days and removes empty folders.  The part that deletes files work fine, but the part that deletes folders is popping up a confirmation window no matter what I do to suppress it.  Here's my code:

```
$date=(get-date).AddDays(-14)
$ConfirmPreference="None"
$DebugPreference="SilentlyContinue"
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"
$VerbosePreference="SilentlyContinue"
$WarningPreference="SilentlyContinue"
$OutputEncoding=[console]::OutputEncoding

function FullNuke ([string] $strPath) {
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $date} | Remove-Item -Force
  #The line below is the one that triggers the confirmation
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Most of the answers I have found say to add -Recurse to my final Remove-Item command, but that would be the opposite of what I want.  If the folder is empty, I want it removed.  If it is not empty, I do not want it removed.  I'm not sure why non-empty folders are even being caught in the first place.

**UPDATE**

After much frustration, I discovered that the second line was processing items in reverse order, thus requiring confirmation.  It was also not properly identifying empty folders, which also triggered confirmation.  I ended up using the following function.

```
function FullNuke ([string] $strPath) {
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $date} | Remove-Item -Force
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Where-Object {@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force).Length -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

I put it here because while it is a solution (it erases files and folders to my satisfaction), it is not an answer to my posted question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-Force` from first `Get-ChildItem` and add `-Recurse` and `-Confirm:$false`.
This will work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and 
        @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | 
            Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} | 
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Removing -Force from the first Get-ChildItem will skip all hidden files.  I do not want to skip hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v3 or higher powershell client you can use the -directory and -file switches for Get-ChildItem and use this:

```
function FullNuke ([string] $strPath) {
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force -File | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $date} | Remove-Item -Force
  Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath -Recurse -Force -Directory | Where-Object {(gci $_.FullName -File -Recurse -Force).count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
}
```

Yes, I added -Recurse to the folder removal because with my testing no folders with any files in them were being passed to that point, and if it is a folder with nothing but empty folders in it then they all need to go anyway right?

Comment: It makes sense, but unfortunately, I'm restricted to v2.  What is gci?  You use it in the Where-Object portion.

Comment: @SlogmeisterExtraordinaire Sorry, GCI is short for Get-ChildItem