# How to automate nuget installation in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have a script which needs to uninstall an MSI program, and for this i use "Get-Package" cmdlet,
the thing is, while the script is running when i need to use this cmdlet, it's suddenly popup a prompt window which asks me do i want to download the nuget package manager, i've tried to add

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
```

before the uninstall command (  `Get-Package '*appname'|Uninstall-Package`)

but it's not changed any thing..

Thanks alot for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually well documented all over the internet.

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Confirm:$false
```

Such as on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819987/suppress-automatic-confirmation-of-deletion-in-powershell)

Comment: Believe me my friend that i've did some searching before posting this question :)
But thanks anyways